# Is there a way to save and run Big Query code in a continuous sequence?

Tags: google-bigquery

Newbie to Big Query, looking for a way to run my code in sequence. I have been trying to save code in the code editor but it is not neat especially when it comes to complex and multi-step queries

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at big query scheduled queries? you can write multiple queries in a single scheduled big query which will run in  sequence which will be saved and you can run it on demand or even schedule it. if you have complex and multi queries as you have mentioned, you can create multiple schedule queries and trigger them based on sequence using pub sub topics. If you can let me know in detail what exactly your requirement is, I can provide more details.

Once you write your query in query editor, you can use below option.

[image]

If you create multiple schedule queries and want to run in a sequence, there are multiple ways to trigger a schedule big query using another big query. Using pub sub topics and cloud functions as shown below or I need to understand what scheduling options are being used.

[image]

I can provide more details if you provide the exact requirements.